# allocating memory for vectors

Tags: c++, vector

Can anyone tell me why this program is crashing?
Basically I was trying to create a vector of arrays?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <int> arr[100];
    arr[0][0] =5;
    printf("%d",arr[0][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are creating an **array of 100 empty vectors**, not a vector of arrays (why not a vector of vectors?). There is nothing there to use.

Use this:

```
vector<vector <int>> arr(100, vector <int>(size));
```

with size the size you require.

If you want a vector of arrays, use:

```
vector<array<int, 100>> arr(size);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you did not allocate elements in `vector`. You are confusing `std::vector` with static arrays, they need calling `.push_back()` or doing a prealloc.

So in your code `arr[0]` will work because this is a reference to first element of static array, while `arr[0][0]` is crashing.

Try

```
arr[0].push_back(5)
```

Comment: can you tell me what will be  the value of a[0] ? will it be the address of first row of array inside that vector?

Comment: The value of `a[0]` is empty `std::vector`. Not first row, nor second, it is empty until you fill it with `push_back()`

Comment: I read that we cannot store arrays inside vector (vector <arr[]> v) But what is happening here are we storing the address of every row array in the vector?
Please help I am new to cpp

Comment: `std::vector` is a class, it is not just a `row`. This class has internal pointers to manage dynamic memory allocation and you should not think of it as a row. So you have static array of 100 classes, where each class is an instance of `std::vector`

Comment: That's the mistake you made, you don't have a vector of arrays, it's not possible. That's what std::array is there for (see my answer).